# Date format lacks year for many lists

Tags: feature-request, profile-page, timestamps

In many lists, like profile->activity, only month and day is shown directly, but not the year. [ISO 8601](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114611/inconsistency-in-use-of-international-standards-based-dates-and-times) format is shown only when hovering over the date.  This is quite distracting.

Other lists that are offered in different orders (chronological/by rating) like questions or answers always contain the year for older dates in 'yy format.

Comment: I've seen this too; it's sometimes confusing, especially when there are big gaps in a user's activity.